# Суммы положительных и отрицательных чисел выведенные в консоль в виде объекта

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Да, у меня тоже как раз подобная задачка как по указанной ссылке и в плане решения теперь мне стало ясно. Только хотела уточнить 1 момент, мне в консоли надо, чтоб суммы положительных и отрицательных чисел вывелись в виде объекта. Например, {-54, 74 }, а не [ -54, 74 ]. Как бы это можно было провернуть?

[Дан массив с числами. Найдите отдельно сумму положительных и отрицательных элементов массива. Выведите суммы на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504382/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5/1523360?noredirect=1#comment2737204_1523360)

Comment: `в виде объекта. Например, {-54, 74 }` только вот так `const o = {'-54': 74 }`

Comment: Разница между объектом и массивом, в том что **у объекта всегда должен быть определённый ключ**, и есть некий набор правил каким этот ключ должен быть. @ksa Чёткий ответ ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только в таком виде:

```js
let arr = [10, 2, -7, -15, 3, -2];

let obj = arr.reduce((a,e) => {
  a[e > 0 ? 'pos': 'neg'] += e;
  return a;
},{pos:0,neg:0})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Благодарю всех за помощь!